# Como esperar um método terminar no JS?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Olá,

Não consigo fazer com que o JS aguarde o método terminar a execução antes de mostrar o retorno, alguém pode me ajudar?

Método:

```
getValor(jogador) {
        const id_grupo = this.props.grupoSelected.id;
        if (jogador.financeiro) {
            const arrayFinanceiro = Object.keys(jogador.financeiro);
            if (arrayFinanceiro) {
                arrayFinanceiro.forEach((grupoKey) => {
                    if (grupoKey === id_grupo) {
                        return jogador.financeiro[grupoKey];
                    }
                });
            } else return 0;
        } else return 0;
    }
```

JSX:

```
<Text>{ this.getValor(jogador) }</Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript é assíncrono. 
Para tornar seu método ser síncrono você tem que utilizar o async/await. Veja o exemplo

```
 async function getUserFullData(){ 
    var userData = await getUser(); 
    var userAddress = await getUserAddr(userData); 
    console.log(userData, userAddress); 
}

getUserFullData();
```

Dê uma olhada na documentação também https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas